# iPhone - AudioQueueLevelMeterState - What are the units for the power?

Tags: iphone, audio

In iPhone's library, AudioQueue.h file has a structure AudioQueueLevelMeterState.
It has two floats -> mAveragePower and mPeakPower
What are the units stored in them. 
Is it decibels or not?

Answer (score 0):

Since neither the documentation nor header comments say so I think it is assumed to be the only standard unit. As far as I know, the decibel is the only unit of ***power*** for sound.

There are other units for measuring sound but only the decibel measures power (in the scientific sense.)

Comment: Thanks for the update. But decibels are measured from -160 to 0. And the ouput power given is from 0 to 1. That's why I got doubt whether its decibel or not.